# Jenkins jobs now fail after upgrading Jenkins kubernetes plugin from 1.14.2 --> 1.26.0. Plugin update changes build dir path- re-clarifying question

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins version is 2.222.4.
We upgraded the jenkins kubernetes plugin from 1.14.2 --> 1.26.0. 
What this has done is pre-pluginupgrade, the jenkins slave would mount /home/jenkins as rw so it could use .gradle files in there for its build.

Post plugin upgrade, home/jenkins is now change to **readonly**, and instead the dir called /home/jenkins/agent has become the read/write.
However the build job now has no more r/w access to files in home/jenkins which it needs.

I did a df -h on our slave jnlp pod pre upgrade (k8splugin-V1.14.2) and see the following:

`Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                 119.9G      5.6G    109.1G   5% /
/dev/nvme0n1p2          119.9G      5.6G    109.1G   5% /home/jenkins`

and can see its mounted as read/write

`cat /proc/mounts | grep -i jenkins
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home/jenkins ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0`

Post plugin upgrade if I run a df -h I don't even see  /home/jenkins mounted only:
`/dev/nvme0n1p2  120G  5.6G  110G   5% /etc/hosts`

and if I cat /proc/mounts I only see this post upgrade

`jenkins@buildpod:~$ cat /proc/mounts | grep -i jenkins
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home/jenkins/agent ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 /home/jenkins/.jenkins ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0`

Also seeing this in the jenkins job log but not sure if it is relevant:
`WARNING] HOME is set to / in the jnlp container. You may encounter troubles when using tools or ssh client. This usually happens if the uid doesnt have any entry in /etc/passwd. Please add a user to your Dockerfile or set the HOME environment variable to a valid directory in the pod template definition.`

Any ideas or workarounds would be most welcome as badly stuck by this issue.
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague just figured this out. He found it goes back to a change the plugin developers made sometime in August 2019, to be compatible with Kubernetes 1.18. That's when they changed the default workspace in release 1.18.0 of the plugin. It was spotted and supposed to be fixed here github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/pull/713 but it persists in our case. Workaround is to hardcode into the jenkinsfile of each job `workingDir: '/home/jenkins'` under the container